# How to assign folder permissions without subsequent sub-folder permission inheritance

Tags: inheritance, permissions, directory

I have the following folder structure: ParentFolder1. 
Within ParentFolder1, there are multiple child folders: ChildFolder1, ChildFolder2..,ChildFolder700

Does anyone have a script sample where I could grant UserX access only to ParentFolder1 and ChildFolder1? I understand that if I grant Userx access to ParentFolder1, it will trickle down to all ChildFolders(1-700). I am trying to prevent this from happening. I am new to Google scripting and would appreicate any help or suggestions?

Thanks,
JV

Comment: Is this question about Microsoft DOS?

Comment: This is related to google apps script. Apologies for not clarifying this in my post